# How to use css to vertical align mixed elements?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

So my boss says to me, "Hey you! Make it so there is a banner at the top our website that has our phone numbers and the signup for our newsletter in one line." Although I am old and easily confused I figured it was high time to stop using tables and do it with css like god intended.

```
<div id="hdr">
<i>Call us today</i> &nbsp;&nbsp; CorpHQ - nnn.nnn.nnnn &nbsp;&nbsp;
<i>Sign up for our newsletter:</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<form action="signup.php" method="post">
<input name="email" type="text">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
</div>
```

However, no matter what I try to do get things vertically aligned, I get all sorts of inexplicable results depending upon whether the site is viewed in Chrome, IE6, IE7, and Firefox. (I'm mainly talking about the size and vertical centering of the field and submit button.)

1) Is there a BIG SECRET here I don't know about?

2) Should I just go back to my original plan to use a table?

3) Is CSS actually a cruel trick invented by space aliens to keep us occupied while they print up copies of "To Serve Man"?

Halp!

Comment: Just to be sure, don't you mix vertical with horizontal? I have a hard time in understanding and visualizing the final result. Some sketchup (paint? ASCII?) may help a lot.

Comment: Post some CSS if you would please. And, as a stab in the dark, try changing line-height on the elements/container to get a consistent vertical alignment (e.g. everything gets "centered" on the line-height)

Comment: In ASCII:

Call us today CorpHQ - nnn.nnn.nnnn Sign up for our newsletter: _f_i_e_l_d_ SUBMIT

Just one line of stuff straight across.

I miss tables. *snif*

Answer (score 2):

1. No
2. No
3. No

Put each item in it's own div, and all those divs in a parent div.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="contact"></div>
  <div class="signup_form"></div>
</div>
```

Now, you can align the parent div (wrapper) however you want, and each element contained inside the wrapper will start out with the placement of the wrapper (then you can change each element as needed).

```
.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0px auto; /* centered */
}

.contact {
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 80px; /* will be 80 pixels off of the center */
  float: left; /* placed to the left */
}

.signup_form {
  float: right;
}
```

Now the contact and signup form will be on the same line.

Comment: I tried a variant on this where the text was in one wrapper, the field in another, and the submit button in yet another - it looked great in Chrome, but when I went to IE7 nothing was vertically aligned like I expected.

I was hoping I had missed the class that talked about a magical CSS command that would do this, uh, er, like a table would.

I'll go back and add back the extra wrappers and see if I can determine what my biggest stumbling block is.

Comment: if you do that, try setting the margin to 0px `margin: 0px;` you might have an alignment issue due to unnoticed spacing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="hdr">
<form action="signup.php" method="post">
<i>Call us today</i> &nbsp;&nbsp; CorpHQ - nnn.nnn.nnnn &nbsp;&nbsp;
<i>Sign up for our newsletter:</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;

<input name="email" type="text">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
</div>
```

The form displays as a block. So it will "jump" to the next line. This is only a quick+dirty fix. You should use labels, stop using `<i>`, stop using `&nbsp;` for spacing and probably others I don't know about. Oh and also make sure you're not in [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

Comment: KK, form as block answers an unasked question. Thanks. I promise I'll give up <i> and &nbsp; right after I get my next paycheck. Don't push me too hard: I may fall down and never get up. ;)